# Override static member in DaemonRunner

Tags: python, python-daemon

I'm trying to override the DaemonRunner in the python standard daemon process library (found here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/)

The DaemonRunner responds to command line arguments for start, stop, and restart, but I want to add a fourth option for status.

The class I want to override looks something like this:

```
class DaemonRunner(object):
    def _start(self):
        ...etc

    action_funcs = {'start': _start}
```

I've tried to override it like this:

```
class StatusDaemonRunner(DaemonRunner):
    def _status(self):
        ...

    DaemonRunner.action_funcs['status'] = _status
```

This works to some extent, but the problem is that every instance of DaemonRunner now have the new behaviour. Is it possible to override it without modifying every instance of DaemonRunner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would override action_functs to make it a non-static member of `class StatusDaemonRunner(DaemonRunner)`.

In terms of code I would do:

```
class StatusDaemonRunner(runner.DaemonRunner):
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.action_funcs = runner.DaemonRunner.action_funcs.copy()
        self.action_funcs['status'] = StatusDaemonRunner._status
        super(StatusDaemonRunner, self).__init__(app)
    def _status(self):
        pass  # do your stuff
```

Indeed, if we look at the getter in the implementation of DaemonRunner ([here](https://github.com/arnaudsj/python-daemon/blob/master/daemon/runner.py#L168)) we can see that it acess the attribute using self

```
    def _get_action_func(self):
    """ Return the function for the specified action.

        Raises ``DaemonRunnerInvalidActionError`` if the action is
        unknown.

        """
    try:
        func = self.action_funcs[self.action]
    except KeyError:
        raise DaemonRunnerInvalidActionError(
            u"Unknown action: %(action)r" % vars(self))
    return func
```

Hence the previous code should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it doesn't work because _status is not defined within __init__(). self._status doesn't work as expected either, because it will be called with self explicitly passed from DaemonRunner::do_action. Could do `self.action_funcs['status'] = self._status` and `def _status(self, self_parent)`, but that seems nasty..

Comment: You're right, I didn't try the code. Please have a look at the edited answer. Basically, I now call the base class constructor after altering action_functs. In addition, I specify a static reference to method _status.